# Как получить request url websocket-подключения зная ссылку на страницу?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

С помощью `DevTools` мне удалось найти `websocket` соединение и его `request url`.

Можно ли это автоматизировать с помощью `Python` (или в крайнем случае `JavaScript` или консоль), чтобы по одной только ссылке на активную шахматную партию (например, https://lichess.org/y0LsSPFV) я мог получить `request url` этого `websocket`?

Или возможно есть какая-либо консольная команда, чтобы это сделать? (тогда с помощью python я уже прочитаю вывод консоли)

Мои поиски пока что привели меня к команде netstat благодаря которой я увидел среди вывода `socket.lichess.o.https socket5.lichess..https socket2.lichess..https`. Возможно, я близок к цели?

В дальнейшем, зная `request url` сокета, планирую прослушивать шахматную партию и вызывать обработчик на каждый сделанный ход (эта часть у меня уже на самом деле реализована, осталось только узнать `request url`...)

Спасибо всем кто поможет
[image: DevTools -> Network -> WS Видно websocket соединение и его request url]